# Play An MP3 in Angular Using <audio> Tag

Tags: angular

Very new to Angular.  I'm trying to play a hard-coded mp3 file with Angular

I have the mp3 file in the same path as my component, and I'm trying to use the  tag like:

```
<audio controls src={{./name-of-file.mp3}}></audio>
```

However, this is not working. Is there a straightforward way to hardcode a brief mp3 file into my app?

Comment: Does `src="./name-of-file.mp3"` not work?

Comment: I tried that originally, but it doesn't work. I can see the audio player in the browser, but the file does not play with this code: ```<audio controls><source src="./name-of-file.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" /></audio> ```

Comment: Okay, actually it looks like Angular just didn't like the file location. Moving the audio file to another folder did the trick: ```<audio controls><source src="../../audio/name-of-file.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" /></audio> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, actually it looks like Angular just didn't like the file location. Moving the audio file to another folder did the trick: `<audio controls><source src="../../audio/name-of-file.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" /></audio>`

Answer (score 2):

any img/icon/music should be put in the assets folder

or you could configure in angular.json other assets folders paths

Answer (score 0):

**for audio**

```
<audio controls>
    <source src="horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
    <source src="horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

Answer (score 0):

This also should work. In your typescript file, You can set myAudio variable with the audio source

```
<audio controls><source [src]="myAudio" /></audio>
```